# dynamically changing a part of javascript code based on the result of a cgi script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to dynamically change a part of a javascript code based on the result of a cgi script that returns 0/1.

my web page code :

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=hhT96DQs

it is a map canvas, using google map api

i need to add an additional marker when the result of the cgi script is 0.

so my code to do that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var result;
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'http://172.27.140.52/cgi-bin/lockdownsubscribe.cgi',
success:function(data) {
alert(data);
if(data=='0')
{
document.getElementById("lockdownmap").innerHTML="function markerObject(latValue,longValue,buildingName, map){ this.marker=new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(latValue, longValue), map: map,title:buildingName});var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon33.png';var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.719900, -95.327981); var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng,map: map, icon: image, title: 'Lockdown_Beta'  });} ";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("lockdownmap").innerHTML="function markerObject(latValue,longValue,buildingName, map){this.marker=new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(latValue, longValue), map: map, title:buildingName }); ";
}
}

})
</script>
```

can someone help me out with this please?

i tried dividing the original script into parts and giving id's to the divisions and tried changing the inner html of that div.

but didn't work out.

I am new to javascript and i couldn't figure out what to do.

Comment: It looks like you are putting Javascript into an innerHTML, which doesn't work. It just prints it out there as text, it won't run it.

Comment: @matcarlson yes... i've been trying all the possibilities to do that since morning and it didn't run.. can you suggest me a solution by which i dint end up wrecking the original functionality of the script and accomplish my taks as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not adept with Google Maps API - You should be able to run the code starting from `marker=new google.maps.Marker` on, deleting everything prior to that. If that doesn't work, I'd check into ways to programtically add map pins/markers. You may need to use something like `document.getElementById("id").marker[] = new google.maps.Marker`, although that's just a guess.

Comment: Why not have two different EXISTING functions and just call the appropriate one?

Comment: @Diodeus i already tried that by having 2 functions markerObject and markerObject1.
That didn't work out.